# How many equivalence classes in a set of well-orders of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, ordinals

The question: 
Let $S$ be a set and $\operatorname{wo}(S)=\{X: X\subseteq S \land (X,\le) \text{ is a well order}\}$. Furthermore, partition $\operatorname{wo}(S)$ into equvialence classes based on order-isomorphic. Call these classes $W_1,W_2,\ldots,W_\omega,\ldots$ and let $W=\{W_1,W_2,\ldots,W_\omega,\ldots\}$.

1. How many elements in $W$ are there?
2. Prove that $|W|>|S|$

My thoughts: Each equivalence class $W_i$ will be order-isomorphic to an ordinal number. I am thinking that this means that $|W|=|S|+1$ as the elements in $W$ will be order-isomorphic to $0,1,\ldots,S$ respectively. Could anyone please help me prove this?

For 2., I am a bit unsure. If $|S|=\omega$, say, then $S=\omega$. I'm not sure then whether we should view $|W|$ as $\omega+1$ or $1+\omega=\omega$. Thus, I am not sure how to prove this assertion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: $\omega$ is an ordinal, not a cardinal. You should be using $\aleph_0$ instead.

Comment: Once you take care to distinguish between ordinals and cardinals, you'll discover a problem in part 2, which will point to a problem in part 1.

Comment: The number of equivalence classes is the cardinal successor $|S|^+$. (E.g. if $S=\omega$ then $|W| = \aleph_1$.) Each equivalence class $w$ has as many elements as there are bijections between subsets of $S$ of size $|w|$. If $S$ is finite then there's only one order type of a well-ordering of any subset $X \subseteq S$, determined by the size of $X$, and there are $n+1$ possible sizes of $X$ where $n = |S|$, so in this case it's still true, as $n+1 = n^+$.

Comment: If $S$ is countably infinite then the cardinality of $W$ is that of the set of all countably infinite ordinals, and that is $\aleph_1>\aleph_0$. $\qquad$

Comment: What is $\le$ in your definition of $\operatorname{wo}(S)$? Don't you mean$$\operatorname{wo}(S)=\{(X,\le):X\subseteq S\land(X,\le)\text{ is a well order}\}?$$

Comment: @bof Yes, sorry you're right. $\le$ is just the normal meaning when applied to ordinals.

Comment: @Christopher: It’s perfectly acceptable to use $\omega$ for the cardinal as well as for the ordinal; for any ordinal $\alpha$, $\omega_\alpha$ is both an ordinal and a cardinal. This is a standard usage; see, e.g., Ken Kunen’s set theory text (and numerous papers).